# How do I arrange RadioButtons?

Tags: android, xml, attributes, radio-button, radio-group

I have 4 RadioButtons in a RadioGroup, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Button 1"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="Button 2"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:text="Button 3"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:text="Button 4"/>

    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want RadioButton 2 to be right of RadioButton 1, I want RadioButton 3 to be below of RadioButton 1 and I want RadioButton 4 to be right of RadioButton 3.

The normal attributes like

```
android:layout_below=""
```

and

```
android:layout_toRightOf""
```

don't work for RadioButtons. How can I place the RadioButtons the way described above in XML here?

Comment: Check my answer below. I have added a working code with output. hope this will help

Comment: If my answer seems useful then please give an up-vote. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1: Using `LinearLayout`:**

1. Add `LinearLayout` as a direct child of `RadioGroup` and give it `vertical` orientation using `android:orientation="vertical"`.
2. Add another two `LinearLayout` inside above `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"` and `android:weightSum="2"`.
3. Put `button1` and `button2` into first horizontal `LinearLayout` and put `button3` and `button4` into second horizontal `LinearLayout`.
4. Give all 4 `buttons` weight `1` by using attribute `android:layout_weight="1"`.

**Try this:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button 1"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button 2"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button 3"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button 4"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**SOLUTION 2: Using `RelativeLayout`:**

1. Add `RelativeLayout` as a direct child of `RadioGroup` and put all the `RadioButton` inside this `RelativeLayout`.
2. Add attribute `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"` to `button2` to show it `right` of `button1`.
3. Add attribute  `android:layout_below="@id/button1`" to `button3` to show it `below` of `button1`.
4. Add attribute `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button3"` and `android:layout_alignBottom="@id/button3"` to `button4` to show it right of `button3`.

**Try ths:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button 1"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button1"
                android:text="Button 2"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/button1"
                android:text="Button 3"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button3"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/button3"
                android:text="Button 4"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**FYI,** You can use `padding` or `margin` between `buttons` as per your needs.

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. If my answer seems useful then please give an up-vote.

Comment: Now the lay-out is like I wanted it to have, it was very useful! But I've got a big side effect now. Every button can be selected together, and they're all on now. How can I solve this? (I tried the LinearLayout-way.)

Comment: Its better if you can post this problem as different question.

Comment: I'll try that! If you have an answer, go here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43563150/how-can-i-put-radiobuttons-as-grandchildren-from-their-radiogroup-a-good-way

Comment: I know that problem will occur. So I developed a library which is actually a RelativeRadioGroup. I gave details in the answer and also in your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43563150/how-can-i-put-radiobuttons-as-grandchildren-from-their-radiogroup-a-good-way/43563202#43563202 question.

Comment: Gert-Jan Schaap I have answered to your second question. please check it

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you not to increase View Hierarchy by using nested Nested Layout (Linear/Relative) inside a RadioGroup. Also you will not get single selection feature using Nested Layout. RadioGroup actually extends LinearLayout. So it has only the capability of arranging RadioButtons either Vertically or Horizontally. Here I shared the link 
[RelativeRadioGroup](https://github.com/mmb4rn0/RelativeRadioGroup)
of my Library which is actually a RelativeRadioGroup so that you can arrange RadioButtons as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code,

```
    <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:oriendtation="horizontal"/>

  <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Button 1"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="Button 2"/>


 </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:oriendtation="horizontal"/>


        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:text="Button 3"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:text="Button 4"/>


 </LinearLayout>
```

I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
tools:ignore="NewApi">



<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Button 1"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="Button 2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:text="Button 3"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:text="Button 4"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RadioGroup>
```