# How can I put RadioButtons as grandchildren from their RadioGroup a good way?

Tags: android, xml, attributes, radio-button, radio-group

I have 4 `RadioButtons` arranged this way:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button 1"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button 2"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button 3"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button 4"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is, now every `RadioButton` can be pressed and be selected together. That shouldn't happen. There must always be one or zero `RadioButtons` selected, not multiple. In a normal `RadioGroup`, this problem doesn't occur. I think it's because of the `LinearLayout's` in it, but I need them for the rest of my app. How can I solve this problem?

How can I put `RadioButtons` as grandchildren from their `RadioGroup` a good way?

Comment: Try to avoid this practice. This will increase the ViewHierachy. And handling selection programmatically will be very clumsy. Rather you follow my answer. Hope you will get what you want. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `LinearLayout` inside `RadioGroup`, `RadioGroup` loses its basic `functionality` to `toggle` button `states` and also its override method `onCheckedChanged()` never be called.

To solve this problem, you have to change the `RadioButton` states `programmatically`.

**Here is a complete solution:**

```
public class RadioGroupActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RadioButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton radioButton1;
    RadioButton radioButton2;
    RadioButton radioButton3;
    RadioButton radioButton4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio_group);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Hello Android");

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        radioButton3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        radioButton4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.button4);

        radioButton1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        radioButton2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        radioButton3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        radioButton4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean status) {
        if (status)
        {
            switch (compoundButton.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:
                    radioButton2.setChecked(false); radioButton3.setChecked(false); radioButton4.setChecked(false);

                    // Do something
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), radioButton1.getText() + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case R.id.button2:
                    radioButton1.setChecked(false); radioButton3.setChecked(false); radioButton4.setChecked(false);

                    // Do something
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), radioButton2.getText() + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case R.id.button3:
                    radioButton1.setChecked(false); radioButton2.setChecked(false); radioButton4.setChecked(false);

                    // Do something
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), radioButton3.getText() + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case R.id.button4:
                    radioButton1.setChecked(false); radioButton2.setChecked(false); radioButton3.setChecked(false);

                    // Do something
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), radioButton4.getText() + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: i think he is talking about arranging the radiobuttons.. in layout...efficiently

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you not to increase View Hierarchy by using nested Nested Layout (Linear/Relative) inside a RadioGroup. Also you will not get single selection feature using Nested Layout. RadioGroup actually extends LinearLayout. So it has only the capability of arranging RadioButtons either Vertically or Horizontally. Here I shared the link 
[RelativeRadioGroup](https://github.com/mmb4rn0/RelativeRadioGroup)
of my Library which is actually a RelativeRadioGroup so that you can arrange RadioButtons as you wish and specially selection will not be affected.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put any other layout in RadioGroup. So if you still want to put all your RadioButtons in Linear layout, You'll have to do little extra work.

Do it programmatically, When any RadioButton is checked set others unchekced.

Something like

```
RadioButton rbu1 =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
RadioButton rbu2 =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
rbu1.setOnClickListener(first_radio_listener);
rbu2.setOnClickListener(second_radio_listener);
OnClickListener first_radio_listener = new OnClickListener (){
public void onClick(View v) {
  rbu2.setChecked(false);
 }
};
OnClickListener second_radio_listener = new OnClickListener (){
public void onClick(View v) {
  rbu1.setChecked(false);
 }
};
```